# Find coefficient of multivariate polynomial with a limit

Tags: real-analysis

I have a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables, 
and I want to find the coefficient of a certain monomial.

For example, $p(x,y)=x^4+y^4+42x^3y+y^3x+x^2y^2,$
can I rigorously in some way say that
$$\lim_{x,y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(x,y)}{x^3y} = 42$$

Of course, the limit depends on how I let x,y go to infinity,
but is there a path such that I get exactly the coefficient I seek?

I want to apply this to the following problem: I have an equality similar to
$f(x,y) = p(x,y)$ where $f$ is an ugly sum, where the terms are not polynomial (but the entire sum is of course).

Now, I consider $f(x,y)/(x^3y) = p(x,y)/(x^3y)$ as above.

Is it possible here to take limits on both sides in a certain manner,
and see that the coefficient of $x^3y$ in $p(x)$ (provided p is homogeneous),
is the limit of $\lim_{x,y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y)/(x^3y)$ in some way?

I can compute the latter expression in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Along the path $y=cx$, you get a limit of $L(c):=\frac{1+c^4+42c+c^3+c^2}{c}=\frac1c+c^3+42+c^2+c$, so you might say that your $42$ is the constant term of how th elimit depends on the choice of (linear) path. Observe that $L(c)+L(-c)=42+2c^2$, so your 42 is approximated by $L(c)+L(-c)$ for small $c$. With other homogenous polynomials, your mileage may vary ...

Comment: The case I consider is the k:th degree complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial. I get a constant term as above in that case as well...